# Error with survey package svyglm function

Tags: r, survey

I am doing some studywork using PIRLS 2016 and PIRLS 2021 data. I need to perform linear regression with weighted data (I apologize for the non-english language in the code).
To correctly calculate the weighted data I used:

```
imputetas.kopas.X <- lapply(1:5, 
  function(x, dati = X) {
    dati$PV <- unlist(X[, paste0("ASRREA0", x)])
  return(dati)
})
```

Then I created a design using:

```
dizains.X.1 <- svrepdesign(repweights = "TOTWGT", 
                           type = "JK1",
                           scale = 1, 
                           combined.weights = TRUE, 
                           weights = P2016.1$X.TOTWGT, 
                           data = imputationList(imputetas.kopas.X))
```

and

```
survey_design_Regr_ASBGSCR1 <- svydesign(
  ids = 1:nrow(Regr.ASBGSCR1),
  weights = P2016.1$X.TOTWGT,
  data = Regr.ASBGSCR1
)
```

When trying to combine everything in and perform the linear regression:

```
modelis1 <- MIcombine(with(dizains.X.1, svyglm(formulla, design = survey_design_Regr_ASBGSCR1)))
```

This is the "formulla" variable:

```
formulla <- as.formula(paste("X.ASBGSCR ~ X.ASBGERL + X.ASBGSLR + X.ASBH03A + X.ASBG03 + X.ASBGHRL + X.ASBGSSB + X.ASBG06"))
```

And all of those variables are under the same data frame used in the design variable.
I get an error stating:

```
Error in UseMethod("svyglm", design) : 
  no applicable method for 'svyglm' applied to an object of class "svyimputationList"
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should not specify `design=` inside the `with()` call. The point of the `with()` call is that it subsitutes each imputed data set in turn into the expression you supply. For example, on the help page for `with.svyimputationList`

```
designs<-svydesign(id=~id, strata=~sex, data=all)
results<-with(designs, svymean(~drkfre))
MIcombine(results)
```

there is no `design=` argument specified to `svymean`